# how to trace css element errors

Tags: java, css, jsp

I have a JSP file in which I have used many CSS classes. 
I have defined those CSS in .css file. If I don't include .css file in the path then JSP will not work as per expectation. In bigger project how can I trace absence of .css file?
Do we have any browser where I can see/trace CSS errors?

No features of Firebug give any error if we miss to include .css file in the project. I am using Firebug and could not find .css error file by using firebug. We should have prior knowledge that we must have missed to include .css file that is why JSP file is not being render properly. But what if somebody else who doesn't have knowledge which .css(or any other html, jsp, javascript) file to be included then such features like FIREBUG is useful. But in case of .css firebug doesn't give error trace

Comment: IF a CSS file is not loaded, any styles within it will not be displayed in the page.

Comment: _If I don't include .css file in the path then JSP will not work as per expectation_ What does this mean? What do you expect? And what do you get instead? Note: you should not include the css file with jsp, you should include it with the proper html `<link>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You can write a unit test which loads all your JSPs as plain text files and parses their contents for the required path to the CSS file. Something like this perhaps

```
@Test
public void hasCssFile() {
    for (File file : new File(yourJspFolder).listFiles()) {
        String contents = Files.toString(file, Charset.defaultCharset());
        if(!contents.contains("path/to/css"){
            fail("add Css file to " + file.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebug, a Firefox add-on (downloadable from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)), can be used to trace CSS related issues.

Comment: Doesn't need it, Firefox already has built-in Developer Tools

Comment: @backslash try it. it has more feature then DOM Analyzer

Comment: I know it and how it works, but firefox already has built-in developer tools that can show css errors. By the way the OP never said he is using firefox

Comment: no features of Firebug give any error if we miss to include .css file in the project. I am using Firebug and could not find .css error file by using firebug. We should have prior knowledge that we must have missed to include .css file that is why JSP file is not being render properly. But what if somebody else who doesn't have knowledge which .css(or any other html, jsp, javascript) file to be included then such features like FIREBUG is useful. But in case of .css firebug doesn't give error trace.

Comment: @AmitG In the question you say that you are including the css file via JSP. Don't do it, use the proper HTML `<link>` tag, so that if the file isn't found, firebug will tell you. CSS files should not be included server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a servlet filter which checks whether the `.css` file is refered from the JSP output and only enable it for development cycle.

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class CssCheckFilter implements Filter {

    @Override public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {  }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        res. ... // Check the response content here

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

}
```